# Redirecting in 10,..9,... script

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Hy,

I have a 10 sec. delay page.

```
var t = window.setTimeout('redirect(strUrl)', 11000);
```

And function redirect(strUrl) just does document.location

What would be nice if i have a little message displaying at the bottom of my page, for example:  Redirecting in 10 seconds...

"one second later that setTimeout fired"

...Redirecting to destiny in 9 seconds..

etc

ps. and the dots at the end going from left to right you know it. .. ...

I myselft would probably find out how to get that every second of timeout and just with jquery altered the number ...if that would be possible at all.

Comment: ha :D no,..just having problems with myself. ..first to check answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var timeout = 11; // in seconds

var msgContainer = $('<div />').appendTo('body'),
    msg = $('<span />').appendTo(msgContainer),
    dots = $('<span />').appendTo(msgContainer); 

var timeoutInterval = setInterval(function() {

   timeout--;

   msg.html('Redirecting in ' + timeout + ' seconds');

   if (timeout == 0) {
      clearInterval(timeoutInterval);
      redirect(strUrl);
   } 

}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {

  if (dots.html().length == 3) {
      dots.html('');
  }

  dots.html(function(i, oldHtml) { return oldHtml += '.' });
}, 500);
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/eM758/).

If you wanted to have the second(s) thing, replace the appropriate line above with...

```
msg.html('Redirecting in ' + timeout + ' second' + ((timeout != 1) ? 's' : ''));
```

Of course, this works well with English, but probably isn't as easy with other languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by creating a `div` you position absolutely with `bottom` and `left` coordinates, and update the text in the div by looping on each second. Something like this:

```
function redirect(strurl) {
  var seconds = 10;
  var div = $("<div/>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: "0px",
    bottom: "0px"
  }).appendTo(document.body);

  continueCountdown();

  function continueCountdown() {
    --seconds;
    if (seconds >= 0 ) {
      div.text("...Redirecting in " + seconds + " seconds...");
      setTimeout(continueCountdown, 1000);
    }
    else {
      // Redirect here
      document.location = strurl;
    }
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ewini3/3)

Note that that will be *imprecise*, because the timeout will not necessarily fire in exactly one second. But it'll be close.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var count=10;

window.setTimeout(function(){redirect(url)}, 1000);

function redirect(url){
    if(--count==0){
        location.href=url;
        return;
    }
    $("#DIV_TO_DISPLAY_MESSAGE").text("redirecting in " + count+" secs.");
    window.setTimeout(function(){redirect(url)}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Using a string as the first argument to `setTimeout()` is basically using `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable with number of secs, and in setTimeout( ... , 1000 ) call function whitch will decrease number of secs, change content of some-div/span..., and if secs = 0 redirect .

Answer (score 1):

i would go for [countdown-plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). there's an [example available](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html#callback)